# CSS: Horizontal-aligning an element within a div

Tags: css

I am trying to horizontally-align an element (`<div id='content'>`) within a div (`<div id='container'>`)

`content` may be narrower or wider than the container's width. I need it to be **always centered**.

How do you do that using CSS3?

See the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ja26Z/

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally?rq=1) and see if it helps. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can place the `#content` div in another div:

http://jsfiddle.net/ja26Z/6/

Comment: I just realised my container width can also change. But this is the best answer for the question.

Answer (score 2):

you basically had it, just a spelling error. Update your css to American spelling, `text-align:center;`

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ja26Z/3/

Comment: Ah thanks I wonder why it didn't work. But it doesn't solve the problem where the content is wider than the container.

Comment: Yeah that's a hard problem to solve with just CSS. Id be interested in seeing the solution if you find one. Although it would likely be quicker to just write a script...

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/wVGrN/3/

The `#content` will always be aligned to the center of `#container` even when it's wider than the container.

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container { 
    position: relative; top: 10px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid #666; 
    text-align: center; 
}
#content { 
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 94px; 
    border: 3px solid #99ccff; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

**Testing script**

```
/* This script here is only to demonstrate content with various width, it won't be used in production */
$(function(){
    ResizeContent();
});
function ResizeContent(){
    var width = Math.floor((Math.random()*150)+20);
    var marginLeft = -width / 2;
    var borderWidth = 3;
    $('#content').width(width);
    $('#content').css('margin-left', marginLeft-borderWidth);
    setTimeout(ResizeContent, 1000);
}
```